# I want add custom column for mini sidebar in all page in Magento

Tags: magento

I want add my custom sidebar next right column all page.

Please check this link: http://www.wildbuilder.com/images/Untitled-1-Recovered.png

(I explain using image)

There are featured products in the mini sidebar.

I don't want include the mini sidebar into right column. next to right column :)

I already made featured-products.phtml at /catalog/product/ folder.

And I created cms block, featured_products and I put in this code

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/featured-products.phtml"}}
```

And I added code at page.xml like this.

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
            <label>Main Content Area</label>
            <block type="cms/block" name="featured_products">
                            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>featured_products</block_id></action>
                </block>
        </block>
```

Then I added code in 2columns-right.phtml at /template/page/ folde.

like this,

```
<div class="wrapper">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
<div class="page">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
    <div class="main-container col2-right-layout">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
        <div class="main">                
            <div class="col-main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-right sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
</div>
<?php //my slidebar ?>
<div style="float:right;width:92px;vertical-align:top;background-color:#000;margin:-766px 110px 0 0;">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('featured_products') ?>
</div>
</div>
```

But my sidebar is not showing.

What can I do?

Please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Take notice that, magento uses the session's current category to populate the list. Thefore, if you visit category X, category Y should not be available. Also, if you specify a category id then should work only homepage/frontpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chilipepper explain how you can use a category in sidebar.

- [How to list all the products in a single category in a sidebar block](http://www.chilipepperdesign.com/2009/03/23/magento-how-to-list-all-the-products-in-a-single-category-in-a-sidebar-block)